# I need to change display error off in Symfony framework

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change symfony display error reporting to off because right now when error occurred it not display good it always showing my code and i think it's not good. I tried several ways but nothing works I want to tell you i don't have access to ssh terminal. i need to do this task with coding.

[image]

Comment: You don't want to disable it, but fix errors in your code.

Comment: You should check whether a record is found instead of turning error handling off.

Comment: I want to disable this and create some error template like looks like something wrong etc.

Comment: Could be highly subjective, but I think Symfony's error handling is awesome and pretty solid. Do you want to implement something better?

Comment: This **is** wrong, read the error message.

Comment: I understood man, Problem fixed with if else statement

Comment: Thank you Man :)

Comment: Something tells me your problem really isn't "fixed" by disabling error messages..

Comment: are you in production or dev mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have taken care of those errors, but need to to override the error page, or in other words you want to customise the error page, you will need to do following things.

**Create a Template to display errors**

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
      <h1>Page not found</h1>    
      <p>The requested page couldn\'t be located. Checkout for any URL
        misspelling or <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">return to the homepage</a>.
      </p>
    {% endblock %}
```

**Override the default controller**

```
twig:
    exception_controller: App\Controller\ExceptionController::showException
```

**Or if you want to create a new exception controller from the scratch,**

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        # ... be sure autowiring is enabled
        autowire: true
    # ...

    App\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $debug: '%kernel.debug%'
```

I have extracted this from the Symfony documentation. I recommend you to throughly read the Symfony documentation and familiarise yourself in this area. https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

Thank you.